# Wagtail Page Reverse Error when trying to edit a page

Tags: django, django-models, wagtail, wagtail-pageurl

I'm getting the following error:

```
Reverse for 'wagtail_serve' not found. 'wagtail_serve' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

This is a new install and I'm trying to edit the default landing page. I've never had this error before.

```
Django==2.2.1
wagtail==2.5
wagtail-condensedinlinepanel==0.5.2
wagtailmenus==2.13
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Did I miss a setting somewhere? Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a line like `url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),` in your urls.py?